# xgettext from a csv file

Tags: python, xgettext

I have a csv with all the values to be translated...I want to read the csv file and produce a .pot file but when i load and try calling print _(value) no .pot is produced. Not sure why you can't produce a .pot file with dynamic content from a csv.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import csv
import gettext

t = gettext.translation('api_trans', '/path/to/locale/', fallback=True)
_ = t.ugettext

string_list = []
with open('/path/to/csv/file') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  for row in reader:
    if row:
        if row[0] != '':
            print _(%row[0])
```

When I run this script, I see all the values listed however no .pot file is produced if i run:

```
xgettext -d api_trans -o api_trans.pot api_trans.py
```

Specifying an actual string versus a variable with a string value (eg. print _('hello')) does work...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `xgettext` does not actually execute your Python file, but reads as plain text and tries to identify strings which have to be translated. As you are adding a `_(varaible)` and not `_("literal string that xgettext understands")`, it will not recognize it as text that should be translated.

For that to happen, the most direct way I can think of is generating a dummy file that you will feed to `xgettext`, which will contain all the actual values. Now considering your csv file is not really big, you could try to generate a file which will contain a line similar to `print _("the value of the thing you want to translate")` and that will be understood by `xgettext`. Now of course that would not be the optimal way, but its the most straight-forward without having to worry about parsing.

```
import csv
import gettext

t = gettext.translation('api_trans', '/path/to/locale/', fallback=True)
_ = t.ugettext

string_list = []
with open('/path/to/csv/file') as csvfile:
  with open('/path/to/some/other/file', 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
      if row:
          if row[0] != '':
              out.write("print _(%s)\n" % (repr(row[0],))
```

Then you'd execute `xgettext -d api_trans -o api_trans.pot /path/to/that/file`.

Again, this is sub optimal. You might want to look into [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/), and come up with a more effective solution, I'll look into that too.

That's what I got from using Babel:

```
def extract_csv(fileobj, keywords, comment_tags, options):
    """Extract messages from XXX files.
    :param fileobj: the file-like object the messages should be extracted
                    from
    :param keywords: a list of keywords (i.e. function names) that should
                     be recognized as translation functions
    :param comment_tags: a list of translator tags to search for and
                         include in the results
    :param options: a dictionary of additional options (optional)
    :return: an iterator over ``(lineno, funcname, message, comments)``
             tuples
    :rtype: ``iterator``
    """
    import csv

    reader = csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        if row and row[0] != '':
            yield (lineno, ',', row[0], 'No comment')
```

Then you would need to include it as an extraction method. The simplest way is to have it in a package in the `PYTHONPATH` and use it as follows:

```
# Some custom extraction method
[extractors]
csv = mypackage.module:extract_csv
[csv: **.ctm]
some_option = foo
```

I'm not entirely sure about that last bit, you can see [here](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/messages.html#writing-extraction-methods) for more details :)

Comment: Thank you! That will do the trick. The reason I'm not going the route of Babel is that the documentation is a little vague with certain key points and rather than spending time trying to incorpoate message extraction with Babel, I'm trying this approach because as you guessed, it's a small list of works that need translating.

Comment: @deecodameeko Ok great then! I got somewhere with Babel, but did not try it yet... so I'll just update here in case you want to give it a try :)